# Express Server + Angular deep link

Tags: angular, express, deep-linking

I'm using Express + Angular to create an SPA. Part of the functionality is an email that contains a link that user's click when resetting their password (`https://[domain].com/reset-password/[token]`).

When the user clicks the link, it takes them to the app landing page (`/`) rather than the reset password page (`/reset-password/[token]`).

How can I handle the deep link from the email, through express, to my angular app?

The Express route I have is:

```
router.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

The Anagular route I have is:

```
{
  path: 'reset-password/:token',
  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/reset-password/reset-password.module').then((m) => m.ResetPasswordModule),
},
```

If I create a link within the Angular app to `reset-password/:token` route, it works. It's only when the link is sent via Express that the issue occurs.

How can I solve this issue without having to rely on using the HashLocationStratergy (`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})`) solution that I've used in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you are sending the static files of angular. But here is an full example. Your problem is how are you serving the static files.

```js
// Express will serve all static files from public folder
const publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './public');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
```

Then, if express doest found a file, ej. `/home`, is not a file is an angular route, send the `index.html` **NOT REDIRECT**

```js
// Put this after all your api routes
const indexHtml = path.resolve(__dirname, './public/index.html');
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(indexHtml);
});
```

This is an exmple when express is serving the static files, but this is no the better approach, the recommended is to use an cdn or a proxy(like ngnix) to serve the static files.

PS. I dont speak english very well.